# Writing a JPanel subclass that will obey GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, preferredsize

I built a class that extends `JPanel`, and I have been setting a size on it every time. But now I need multiple instances of that `JPanel` sub-class to exist on another panel. I am using `GridBagLayout`, but my components disappear when I resize the `Frame` or take away the `setSize(800,100)` from the `JPanel` subclass. How do I built components that will obey these `layout managers`?

I want my custom component to be able to fit to the size that the layout manager asks for.

Here is my custom component

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{
    private Rectangle offdutyRect, sbRect, driveRect, onRect;
    private int delta = 60;
    private int[][] gridArray;
    int draggedStartX = -1;
    int draggedStartY = -1;
    private int dutyStatusSpacing = 60;
    private int totalSpacing = 80;

    public GridPanel(){
    super();
    this.setSize(new Dimension(800, 100));//without this it doesn't display
    this.addMouseMotionListener((MouseMotionListener) this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    int gridArrayColumns = 24*60/delta;
    gridArray = new int[4][gridArrayColumns];

    int r = 0;
    int rHeight = this.getHeight()/4;
    offdutyRect = new Rectangle(this.getX() + dutyStatusSpacing, this.getY() + r*rHeight, this.getWidth() - totalSpacing, rHeight);
    r++;
    sbRect = new Rectangle(this.getX() + dutyStatusSpacing, this.getY() + r*rHeight, this.getWidth() - totalSpacing, rHeight);
    r++;
    driveRect = new Rectangle(this.getX() + dutyStatusSpacing, this.getY() + r*rHeight, this.getWidth() - totalSpacing, rHeight);
    r++;
    onRect = new Rectangle(this.getX() + dutyStatusSpacing, this.getY() + r*rHeight, this.getWidth() - totalSpacing, rHeight);

    Rectangle rect = null;
    for(r = 0; r < gridArray.length; r++){
        if(r == 0){
        rect = offdutyRect;
        }else if(r == 1){
        rect = sbRect;
        }else if(r == 2){
        rect = driveRect;
        }else if(r == 3){
        rect = onRect;
        }

        //I haven't actually derived any of these things, just my best guesses.
        int len = gridArray[r].length;
        int width = (int) (rect.getWidth()/len);
        rect.setSize((int)(width*len), (int) rect.getHeight());
    }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.clearRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    //the center black bar for duty status "placeholders"
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
    g.drawRect((int)offdutyRect.getX(), (int)offdutyRect.getY() + (int)offdutyRect.getHeight()/2, (int)offdutyRect.getWidth(), 1);
    g.drawRect((int)sbRect.getX(), (int)sbRect.getY() + (int)sbRect.getHeight()/2, (int)sbRect.getWidth(), 1);
    g.drawRect((int)driveRect.getX(), (int)driveRect.getY() + (int)driveRect.getHeight()/2, (int)driveRect.getWidth(), 1);
    g.drawRect((int)onRect.getX(), (int)onRect.getY() + (int)onRect.getHeight()/2, (int)onRect.getWidth(), 1);
    g.setColor(Color.pink);
    g.drawRect((int)offdutyRect.getX(), (int)offdutyRect.getY(), (int)offdutyRect.getWidth(), (int)offdutyRect.getHeight());
    g.drawRect((int)sbRect.getX(), (int)sbRect.getY(), (int)sbRect.getWidth(), (int)sbRect.getHeight());
    g.drawRect((int)driveRect.getX(), (int)driveRect.getY(), (int)driveRect.getWidth(), (int)driveRect.getHeight());
    g.drawRect((int)onRect.getX(), (int)onRect.getY(), (int)onRect.getWidth(), (int)onRect.getHeight());

    //draw the array
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    Rectangle rect = null;
    for(int r = 0; r < gridArray.length; r++){
        if(r == 0){
        rect = offdutyRect;
        }else if(r == 1){
        rect = sbRect;
        }else if(r == 2){
        rect = driveRect;
        }else if(r == 3){
        rect = onRect;
        }

        //I haven't actually derived any of these things, just my best guesses.
        int len = gridArray[r].length;
        int width = (int) (rect.getWidth()/len);

        int height = (int) rect.getHeight() - 2;
        for(int c = 0; c < gridArray[r].length; c++){
        if(gridArray[r][c] == 1){
                int x = (int) (rect.getX() + width*c);
                int y = (int) rect.getY() + 2;
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

And here is how I am adding them to the container using gridbag

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
System.out.println("action performed"  +  panels.size());
removeAll();
repaint();
panels.add(new GridPanel());
int r = 0;
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
for(int i = 0; i < panels.size(); i++){
        JLabel label = new JLabel("day " + i);
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = r;
        this.add(label, c);
        r++;

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = r;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        this.add(panels.get(i), c);
        r++;
}

c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = r;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/res/add.png"));
} catch (IOException ex) { }
JButton addButton = new JButton();
addButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
addButton.addActionListener(this);


 this.add(addButton, c);


    }
```

When I do this "action performed" that is supposed to add it, my custom component shows up in the top left corner, but I have to resize the window to get all the components to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many layout managers make use of the values returned by `getPreferredSize`, `getMinimumSize` and `getMaximumSize`.

`GridBagLayout` is one of those which will, generally, where possible, try and honor all three.

In your custom component, override (at least), the `getPreferredSize` method and return, to the best of you knowledge, the size of the component you need.

If the component is using a layout manager with other components in it, you should always let the layout manager make this determination (which is the default behavior)

**Updated**

Don't forget, when adding or removing components, you may be required to call `revalidate` to force the container hierarchy to update it's layout(s)

Comment: What if I want to write a component that will properly fill horizontally and/or vertically?

Comment: Use a layout manager in the parent container, like `BorderLayout` for example

Comment: I'm using GridBag with fill = horizontal

Comment: Don't forget to use the `weightx` and `weighty` constraints as well

Comment: This can potentially override the `preferredSize`

Comment: My question has changed alot since you answered it, this is a great answer and I think what I added is just specifics that I should work out. One last thing: how do layoutmanagers tell components to be a certain width & height to fill the "Horizontal" fill that a gridbaglayout might require?

Comment: Layout managers will call a combination of `setLocation`, `setSize` or `setBounds` depending on there needs.  It is not recommeneded that you call these methods yourself (unless you're writing a layout manager) as the layout managers will override them as they see fit

Comment: Thanks so much MadProgrammer, <3